# Copy of thread starts new when IIS restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a problem with a thread into my asp.net MVC-4 Website.

The worker thread reads objects from a queue. The queue is a container to processing orders asynchronously.
This works fine until the IIS will restared.

When the thread get a ThreadAbortException, the object will be saved in the queue.

After the restard has the queue one ore more copys from my objects. (the worker thread is running).

I have no idea why it is. My theory is, after the restart the memory copy of the thread will be recycled and put a the object again in the queue.

It is a theory.

Bye Nero

Comment: Threads belong to processes. That thread belongs to the IIS process so when that process restarts, the thread and all its state, memory etc are lost. You should *NOT* be using such threads in ASP.NET anyway. Scott Hansleman explains the options in [How to run background Jobs](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). The best option is probably to use Hangfire. At the very least, use QueueBackgroundWorkItem instead of raw threads

Comment: Maybe the queue doesn't remove the item until the client acknowledges it? What kind of queue is it?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos thanks for your links, this is a interesting article.

Comment: @ stuartd, this is a simple data structure written in C# with functions like enqueue, dequeue,isFull, next ... simple.
The queue save, read or delete the objects over the entityFramework and a dbContext.